# How to use AcrCloud webAPI in reactJs. I'm making a project to recognise music from youtube links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, acrcloud

I am using ACRCloud free trial music recognition in my react app, but getting errors like,

> Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'D:\projects\practice\music-recogniser\node_modules\acrcloud\lib'

I tried going through ACRCloud documentation but it looks like the code they provided is for NodeJs.